# Some ISO on a Zalman VE-350 are not recognized

Tags: iso-image

I have a Zalman VE-350 with a dozen of ISO on it.
It's supposed to be recognized both as a hard drive and a disk drive by the OS, with whichever ISO is selected in the disk drive.
However, a few of the ISO don't seem to work.

In hdd mode, I can do

```
mount win7.iso /tmp/win7
```

and it works fine.

However in disk mode, if I do

```
mount /dev/sr0 /tmp/win7
```

I get

```
mount: /mnt/nas: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sr0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

Most of the ISO work fine, except one of Windows7 and one of Fedora Live.
It's always the same ISO which do not work.
I tried to mount the ISO on multiple computers, none worked.
I have updated the firmware to the latest version available on zalman.com (2.0.2)

Has anyone encountered such an issue before ? How did you solve it ?

If not, how would you go about diagnosing this further ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, i found out that the problem was the iso file. After gettong another iso file everything was ok.
Thanks have a nice day